# Linked list in java

Tags: java, list

i have to write a very easy method for a linked list class but i am having some problems. This method, called `squish()`, takes this list and, wherever two or more consecutive items are
equal (compared using `equals()`), it removes duplicate nodes so that only one consecutive copy remains.  Hence, no two consecutive items in this list are equal upon completion of the procedure.

After `squish()` executes, the list may well be shorter than when `squish()` began.  No extra items are added to make up for those removed.

For example, if the input list is `[ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ]`, the output list is `[ 0 1 0 3 1 0 ]`.

This is my method:

```
public void squish() {
 SListNode current = head;
 boolean end =false;

  while(end == false )
    {


      if(!current.item.equals(current.next.item))
          current=current.next;
      else
      {
          while(current.item.equals(current.next.item) && current.next !=null)
              current.next=current.next.next;
          current=current.next;

      }
    if (current==null)
        end=true;
    }


      }
```

and this is a small main to execute the code.

```
public class main {
public static void main(String args[])
{



    int[] test6 = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    SList list6 = new SList();
    for (int i = 0; i < test6.length; i++) {
      list6.insertEnd(new Integer(test6[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list6.toString() + ":");
    list6.squish();
    String result = list6.toString();
    System.out.println(result);


    int[] test5 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    SList list5 = new SList();
    for (int i = 0; i < test5.length; i++) {
      list5.insertEnd(new Integer(test5[i]));
    }

    System.out.println("squishing " + list5.toString() + ":");
    list5.squish();
    result = list5.toString();
    System.out.println(result);

}

}
```

Debugging the code i can see that the method work fine..only at the end of the list he trhows a null exception pointer. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the `NullPointerException`? Do you know on what line it is being thrown?

Comment: here it is: :Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SList.squish(SList.java:128)
 at main.main(main.java:14)  , the line is "     while(current.item.equals(current.next.item) && current.next !=null)"

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
public void squish() {
    SListNode current = head; //1

    if(current = null) return;  //1a

    while(current.next != null) { //2
       if(current.item.equals(currennt.next.item))
          current.next = current.next.next;  //3
       else 
          current = current.next;  //4
    }
}
```

This is the kind of thing that profs like to assign for recursion, and while most pros don't use recursion I have set up the method that way.

Line 1 is init, you assign the pointer that will traverse the list to the start of the linked list.

Line 1a if there are no elements in the list, then we return.

Line 2 is the base case.  If we only have one element in the list then there is nothing to do.

Line 3 is the induction if we are pointing at a node, we examine the node next door.  If they have an equal value, then we can remove the node next door.

Line 4 is the else of line 3, we have looked at the node next door, and sees that it is not equal.  Therefore we traverse the list.

It might be a useful exercise to traverse the test data provided in the question by hand, then add some System.out.println's to my example to see if you are correct.  I just had to do that today with some tricky code to figure out what was going on.

Comment: +1 for awesome simplification, but would be even more awesome if you added a bit of explanation. ;-)

Comment: Edited for you @tobias_k

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this line:

```
while(current.item.equals(current.next.item) && current.next !=null)
```

Here, the first part of the condition accesses `current.next.item`, even if `current.next` is null, since the second part of the condition (`current.next !=null`) is checked *after* the first (and only if the first evaluates to `true`, see below). To fix it, just reverse the condition:

```
while(current.next !=null && current.item.equals(current.next.item))
```

This way, the expression `current.item.equals(current.next.item)` will only be executed if `current.next !=null` is true ([short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)), i.e., when it's safe to do so.

Also, I think you can drop that first `if` statement. Take a look at @Pete's answer for how to simplify the method.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning that Java does short circuit evaluation. So if the first part (`current.next != null`) is false, it won't even check the second part (`current.item.equals(current.next.item`). That principle is the reason the answer works.

Comment: @BrianJ You are right. I thought that would be clear from the answer, but on reading it again, it's not. Editing...

Answer (score 2):

When the line `if(!current.item.equals(current.next.item))` is executed in the last iteration, `current.next` points to `null` as `current` is the last item in the list and actually *has no next item*.

**EDIT**

In your comment now I see you get the `NullPointerException` in the line

```
while(current.item.equals(current.next.item) && current.next !=null)
```

Well, you should just replace those two conditions with each other: first validate `current.next` isn't `null` and only then equate `current` and `next`:

```
while(current.next !=null && current.item.equals(current.next.item))
```

BTW, you'd still get NPE in the line `if(!current.item.equals(current.next.item))` when your list has only one element. To fix that you can, for instance, just check if `head.next == null`. If so, don't start the `while` loop in the first place.